# Footer : Bootstrap trouble

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created 2 footers, second footer using css `position: absolute` but the result is, the first footer doesn't work anymore.

The result looks like this:

[image: a]

Comment: Can you add working `code` or `url` ??

Comment: As per my understanding add parent div to both footer and give position:absolute class to that parent div.

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/pjWgl.png
i.stack.imgur.com/2o7AW.png   
i.stack.imgur.com/xoVJ7.png

Comment: @herubond insert both footer in one common div and give position:absolute to that div.

Comment: Sharing code as images WON'T help anyone! Please insert the code in a way that it is easy for anyone to copy it and make changes in it.

Answer (score 2):

Please share your code for understanding.

If you are using position: absolute then add top or bottom & left or right and parent div are also position : relative.